# Predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to define a predicate in prolog which takes a list as input and sums the squares of numbers >= 5 and subtract sum of absolute value of numbers <=2.

This is what I have currently :-

```
pred([], 0).
pred([Head|Tail], Result) :-
    gr85(Head),
    pred(Tail, Total),
    Result is Head*Head + Total.

pred([Head|Tail], Result) :-
    leq2(Head),
    pred(Tail, Total),
    Result is Total - Head.

gr85(Number):-
    Number >= 5.

leq2(Number):-
    Number =< 2.
```

My question is how do I exclude anything between 2 and 5. If I input 3 in the list, it returns false.

Expected input

```
pred([3,6,2,-1], Result).
```

Expected output

```
Result= 33 (6*6 -2-1)
```

Comment: I am not very sure but maybe it should be 6*6 - 2 - (-1) = 35?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a 'skip all' clause:

```
weird_sum([_|Tail], Result) :- weird_sum(Tail, Result).
```

I think you will gain some insight into Prolog working when you analyze *where* this clause should be added.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I guess this goes at the last to because the input didn't match the first 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is simpler if you keep it more simple, you can use accumulator to make it simpler. And also it is maybe less typing if you move the condiditional out, like this;

```
weird_sum(List, Sum) :-
    weird_sum(List, 0, Sum).

weird_sum([], Acc, Sum) :- Sum is Acc.
weird_sum([X|Xs], Sum0, Sum) :-
    once( weird_sum_helper(X, Sum0, Sum1) ),
    weird_sum(Xs, Sum1, Sum).

weird_sum_helper(X, Acc, Acc + X*X) :- X >= 5.
weird_sum_helper(X, Acc, Acc - abs(X)) :- X =< 2.
weird_sum_helper(X, Acc, Acc) :- X < 5, X > 2.
```

But the actual answer to your original question is in the last line above, just say that when X is smaller than 5 AND X is larger than 2 than you don't do anything.

But I get different answer from 33 because when number is negative and you subtract you get positive not negative but I am not sure if this is what you mean.

I used `once` once just because you want to do this only once since the three conditions are excluding each other but somehow Prolog doesn't know that it should only take one and tries the others too.

Comment: The reason it is 33 is that it takes absolute value of everything <=2. Forgot to mention that. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnKeaton aha ok you just write abs(X) instead of X I guess? I edited the answer again so now with this answer I get 33 too. But still the answer to your question is just `X < 5, X > 2`.

Comment: @JohnKeaton I do not understand your edit. Prolog does not even have "func"tions, it has "pred"icates, maybe? Call it "foobar" if you want but "func"? Or do you mean it has a strange smell?

Comment: Yeah. That is kinda what I meant by functions. The initial name was well, weird. I used the word functions because it was a body of code which did a certain task. Anyways, I've edited it to pred which would make it easier to understand.

Comment: @JohnKeaton At least one of your classmates or colleagues had a problem with the same assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43091565/7473772 maybe it is OK to keep weird_sum so that it is easier to find?

Comment: In that case, I'm all for it