# How to get a rule to check all the conditions before exiting?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `weird_sum(List, Result)` which takes a `List` of numbers, and computes the sum of the squares of the numbers in the list that are greater than or equal to 5, minus the sum of the absolute values of the numbers that are less than or equal to 2. For example:

```
?- weird_sum([3,6,2,-1], Result).
Result = 33
```

That's 6×6 - 2 - 1.

I'm trying to check using two conditions whether the number is `>= 5` or `<= 2`. But whenever I call the predicate "computerResult" it will only check the first condition and exit. It never reaches the 2nd condition. How do I make it check the 2nd condition if it fails the first condition?

Here is my code:

```
%base case
weird_sum([], 0).       

%figuring out if number is large or small
computeResult(Head, Result + Head*Head):-
    Head >= 5.

computeResult(Head, Result - abs(Head)):-
    Head @=< 2.

%recursive case
weird_sum([Head|Tail], Result):-
    weird_sum(Tail, Result),
    computeResult(Head,Result).
```

Comment: I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43071463/7473772) just yesterday. Maybe it can help you? It looks a bit like yours but it is slightly different.

Comment: If you have searched "[prolog] weird_sum" you would  could have found the other question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it does not *try* the second clause. The problem is the second parameter in the `computeResult/2` predicate. You write `Result + Head*Head`, etc. so that means that Prolog will try to *unify* a number (`0`) with something of the form `+(Result,*(Head,Head))` and this obviously fails.

You can however easily modify the result like:

```
%base case
weird_sum([], 0).
%recursive case
weird_sum([Head|Tail], Result) :-
    weird_sum(Tail, SubResult),
    computeResult(Head,Adder),
    Result is SubResult+Adder.   

%figuring out if number is large or small
computeResult(Head, Head*Head):-
    Head >= 5.
computeResult(Head, -abs(Head)):-
    Head =< 2.
computeResult(Head, 0) :-
    Head < 5,
    Head > 2.
```

You can also add *cuts* (`!`) to the conditions to prevent backtracking over the `computeResult/2` clauses. In that case you can omit the checks in the last clause.

```
%figuring out if number is large or small
computeResult(Head, Head*Head):-
    Head >= 5,
    !.
computeResult(Head, -abs(Head)):-
    Head =< 2,
    !.
computeResult(_, 0).
```

Nevertheless it is more efficient to use an *accumulator*, like:

```
weird_sum(List, Result) :-
    weird_sum(List, 0, Result).

weird_sum([], Result, Result).
weird_sum([Head|Tail], SubResult, Result) :-
    computeResult(Head,Adder),
    SubResult2 is SubResult+Adder,
    weird_sum(Tail, SubResult2, Result).
```

Comment: can't believe i got an answer so quick here, thank you so much. i get it now